# Open link on keybinding

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a simple python script since i've never done anything in python!

**Soo what i have:**
Script will get Data from my API and displays it on my linux bar,
the except will print a message when the data wont come from API, for example when there is no internet connection!

**What i'm looking for:**
currently my API returns 2 values as you can see (sectionName, webTitle),
these are text properties which i'm printing to the bar, i want to add a new property `link = data['response']['results'][0]["link"]` which will contain a link, the question is that i don't want to print the link, i want to open the link on a Key_pressing! How can i achieve this?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import requests

api_key = "API-KEY-HERE"

try:
     data = requests.get("https://content.mysite.com/search?api-key="+api_key).json()

     sectionName = data['response']['results'][0]["sectionName"]
     webTitle = data['response']['results'][0]["webTitle"]

     print(sectionName+': '+webTitle)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:  # This is the correct syntax
     print ('Something went wrong!')
```

Comment: Do you only want to open the link when a specific key is pressed or do you want to open it when any key is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
keyboard.add_hotkey(hotkey, callback, args=(), suppress=False, timeout=1, trigger_on_release=False)
```

function in keyboard library to invoke a callback when you press the hotkey.

https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/